# Unable to select WebView element after switching context in Appium

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios

I am running into a strange problem with webdriverio/appium when trying to test an iOS app. The app has a WebView with a button labeled "Refresh". When I try to test for this button, I get a "not displayed" error (see code below).

```
it('should have the Refresh button', () => {
    WebViewScreen.waitForWebsiteLoaded();

    // Verify that Refresh button is displayed
    WebViewScreen.switchToContext(CONTEXT_REF.WEBVIEW);
    const button = $('button=Refresh');
    expect(button).toBeDisplayed();
    WebViewScreen.switchToContext(CONTEXT_REF.NATIVE);
});
```

Note that I am switching context to WEBVIEW before testing for the button. Looking at Appium logs, the request to find the button (`$('button=Refresh')`) is returning a 404. Tried a different selector: `['button[data-test="refresh-button"]']`, but no go. I even put a browser.debug() and queried in the REPL - still 404 - although I can physically see the button on the screen!

I know that my webdriverio/appium setup is good because the exact same code works for another iOS screen with a WebView and a button - the only difference is the button name.

I have also ruled out the possibility that my selector is incorrect by going to the standalone webpage and testing for that button - no errors in this case! Here's the standalone web page code - only difference is no context switching calls:

```
it('should have the Refresh button', () => {
    browser.url('https://example.site.com/');

    // Verify that Refresh button is displayed
    const button = $('button=Refresh')
    expect(button).toBeDisplayed();
});
```

Any ideas on how to debug this? Are there any nuances about switching to WEBVIEW context that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a breakthrough on this one - thanks to [Alexi's suggestions on the Appium forum](https://discuss.appium.io/t/unable-to-select-webview-element-after-switching-context/30179). Turns out that I had multiple WebViews in my app and I had to switch context to the right one. The trick is to set the `fullContextList` option on Appium to get more information about the available contexts, and then to select the right one.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you switch to regular webview

```
public static void switch(AppiumDriver driver) {
    Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
    for (String context : contextNames) {
        log.debug("Context available:{}", context);
        if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(context, "WEBVIEW")) {
            log.debug("Switch to WEBVIEW");
            driver.context(context);

        }
```

Comment: Hi Johnny, please see my answer based on Alexi's suggestion. There were multiple WebViews and I had to make sure that I select the right one.